# How to align shapes using VBA Loop

Tags: excel, vba

My code loops a range of cells, which in return adds a shape with the cells value if the cell value within the range is greater than 1.

I would like each newly added shape to be evenly positioned to the right of the first added shape.

Currently my code stacks every shape on top of each other.

**Code**

```
Sub foo()
Dim oval As Shape
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim h As Integer
Dim w As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim shp As Object

h = h + 50 + 2
w = w + 200 + 2
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7")



For Each rCell In rng

If rCell > 0 Then

    Set oval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, h + 1, w + 1, 75, 80)

With oval
    .Line.Visible = True
    .Line.Weight = 8
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .TextFrame.Characters.Caption = rCell.Value
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
    .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 22
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With

End If

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some math should do the trick. The `95` is the width of `75` plus a margin of `20`. Adjust as needed.

```
For Each rCell In rng
    If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) Then
        If rCell.Value > 0 Then
            Dim counter As Long
            counter = counter + 1

            Set oval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, h + 95 * (counter - 1), w + 1, 75, 80)

            With oval
                .Line.Visible = True
                .Line.Weight = 8
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .TextFrame.Characters.Caption = rCell.Value
                .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 22
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next rCell
```

Note that [`Shapes.AddShape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addshape) has the arguments *Type*, *Left*, *Top*, *Width*, *Height*, so using `h` and `w` for *Left* and *Top* is a little confusing.

Comment: any way to not have a gap between the shapes if cell =0 ?